# What is there so exceptional about timers in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, event-loop

I want to understand Event Loop better. I read documents, articles, Node.js' API docs. Almost all of them separate Timers:

`setImmediate():`

> setImmediate(callback[, arg][, ...])
>
> To schedule the "immediate"
>   execution of callback after I/O events callbacks and **before setTimeout
>   and setInterval** .

`process.nextTick():`

> process.nextTick(callback[, arg][, ...])#
>
> This is not a simple alias to **setTimeout(fn, 0)**, it's much more
>   efficient. It runs before any additional I/O events (**including
>   timers**) fire in subsequent ticks of the event loop.

Why? What is so exceptional about timer functions in Node.js in the context of Event Loop?

Comment: I think this is just to establish precedence in the event loop.

Comment: "*What is so exceptional about timer functions*" - well, they're *timed*, they're given some time in milliseconds as an argument.

Comment: `process.nextTick()` is more efficient than `setTimeout(fn,0)` because it defers the function until the next stack is called.

Comment: @MaxMastalerz: What is a "*next stack*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These all relate to having really fine grained control over the asynchronous execution of the callback.

The **nextTick()** function is executed the soonest to the point where it's called. It got its name from event loop "tick". Tick represents full turn of the [event loop](http://bytearcher.com/articles/event-loop-10-000ft/) where different sort of events such as timers, io, network are exhausted once. Even though the name today is confusing since it has changed semantics over node versions. The nextTick() callback is executed in the same tick as the calling code. Adding more nextTick()s in the nextTick() callback function aggregates them and they are called in the same tick.

The **setImmediate()** gives the second closest execution. It's almost identical to setTimeout(0) but it is called before all traditional setTimeout() and setInterval() timers. It is processed as the first thing at the beginning of the next tick. You get sort of a fast lane of asynchronous execution that is privileged over the traditional setInterval() and setTimeout(). Adding more setImmediate() callbacks in setImmediate() itself defers them to next tick and they are not executed in the same tick in contrast to how nextTick()s are. This setImmediate() functionality was originally the semantics for nextTick(), hence the name nextTick().

The **setTimeout()** and **setInterval()** work then as expected, having the third closest exeuction point (or later if the timeouts are long).

Comment: How can I know what turn of the Event Loop I'm in at some moment in runtime? How can I determine Event Loop turns when I look at my source code?

Comment: You can't really but nothing changes. All of this still holds: if you want fine grained control over the point when your callback will be executed pick the best fitting function from these: - really super close potentially dangerous if used badly nextTick(), the kinda right way using setImmediate(), or the old way of doing it using setTimeout(0).

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, the order they called is:nextTick()-->setImmediate()-->setTimeout(fn, 0)